# How to approach BST Problems?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I was given this problem:

> You are given a sequence of n distinct integers a0, a1, . . . an−1. In each
>   iteration you pick the maximum number and delete it, the cost of deteting
>   the maximum number is the number of numbers to the left of it. Repeat
>   this n number of times. Given ai
>   ’s implement an O(n log n) algorithm to
>   compute the total cost of n iterations.

I know that we must use BST to solve this problem as it is O(N log N), however, I'm not sure what to do.

I was thinking I could store values and indices in a hashMap and when a deletion is done, we search for that index in BST and add the index values in the path traversed. While deleting the node, however, we must decrement BST index values for all indices > the one to-be-deleted.

I'm not sure if this is feasible and I would love any advice/guidance regarding this :)

Comment: No need BST, just sort, count `sum`, then loop in reverse and keep adding `sum-current` to answer and updating sum value

Comment: @Photon But sorting changes the element positions and we need them to count the number of elemets to the left of the current max.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @0x499602D2 comment is correct, sorting is a right way to go. This problem is yet another application of merge sort, akin to counting inversion.

Merging an element from right decreases cost by the number of elements remaining in left (do you see why?). After the array is fully sorted, the cost is driven down to 0.

I hope it is enough to get you started.